# How to echo a text containing a path in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to echo a particular text to a file. But it end up echoing it in another way. I can't figure where I'm going wrong.

The text I want to echo is

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/
```

And in the script file I set this as

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/" >> /home/$USER/Desktop/output.txt
```

But in the output.txt file, I get

```
export PATH=/home/lijin/bin:/home/lijin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/
```

I want the exact text to be echoed to the file output.txt

I'm using echo since I have to append the already existing file contents and then print this to the file.

Comment: escape is your friend export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/

Comment: @konstructor yes it works thank you

Comment: @anubhava I think you missed something in your answer, I'm getting the same wrong output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single-quote the string to avoid variable-expansion,

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/' >> /home/$USER/Desktop/output.txt
```

Its the *rule-of-thumb*, single-quotes do NOT expand variables in `bash`, only double-quoting does them. Using a single quote around variable names, deprives `$` from doing variable interpolation

Comment: thanks a lot. It works well, and I find your answer well structured, since it has only single quotes

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you. I will come up with more questions in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/" >> /home/$USER/Desktop/output.txt
```

The weak quoting is an option if you want to expand other variables in the string.

For example you might want to do something like this

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/" >> /home/$USER/Desktop/output.txt
```

Comment: your answer works as well. Only an escape character does the job lol. Thank you

Comment: If you are interested there is an excellent explanation for escaping or single quoting here http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: Wow, that is a very useful guide. Thanks again :)